# eval-when-compile: defsubst vs defmacro vs define-inline

Tags: elisp-macros, byte-compilation

I defined some simple functions in init.el, for example `my-cache-file`:

```
(defconst my-cache-directory
  (expand-file-name ".cache" user-emacs-directory)) ; ~/.emacs/.cache

(defun my-cache-file (x)
  (expand-file-name x my-cache-directory))          ; ~/.emacs/.cache/x

(setq savehist-file
      (my-cache-file "savehist"))

(setq backup-directory-alist
      `(("." . ,(my-cache-file "backups/"))))
```

This seemed like a good use-case for `defsubst`:

```
(defsubst my-cache-file (x) ...)
```

Then I started learning about compilation, and wanted to further optimize. I naively tried:

```
(defsubst my-cache-file (x)
  (eval-when-compile (expand-file-name x my-cache-directory)))
```

but the compiler complained (rightly) about the free variable `x`, so instead I wrapped the calling code:

```
(setq savehist-file
      (eval-when-compile (my-cache-file "savehist")))

(setq backup-directory-alist
      `(("." . ,((eval-when-compile (my-cache-file "backups/"))))
```

That last caller should probably be evaluating the whole alist at compile time, though, so I pulled the `eval-when-compile` up:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      (eval-when-compile `(("." . ,(my-cache-file "backups/")))))
```

I'd like to avoid littering my code with more `eval-when-compile` calls than necessary, and I wonder if there's a better approach I could take using macros or `define-inline`. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html) makes `define-inline` sound promising:

> Functions defined via define-inline have several advantages with respect to macros defined by defsubst or defmacro:
>
> - They can be passed to mapcar (see Mapping Functions).
> - They are more efficient.
> - They can be used as place forms to store values (see Generalized Variables).
> - They behave in a more predictable way than cl-defsubst (see Argument Lists in Common Lisp Extensions for GNU Emacs Lisp).

But the syntax looks cumbersome, and I can't find a single example of it being used in the wild. Nor can I find any explanation of it's claim that defsubst is less efficient.

Has anyone used `define-inline`, or is there a different macro I should look into, or should I just stick with `defsubst`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say stick with **`defun`**.

If you want to try `define-inline`, which is new (it doesn't even have a doc string yet!), go ahead.

But *think* about how much you want or need inlining. It is rare to need it, IMO (certainly not for the kinds of thing you show here, but they are no doubt just to get the question across).

I would definitely recommend *not* to use `defsubst`. You likely don't need it, and it just gets in the way.  It might have had a use case in 1985, but I know of no place where it is useful now.  `define-inline` is apparently an attempt to get the benefit of `defsubst` without the downside.

This question might be primarily opinion-based.  This answer is just one opinion, in any case.

Comment: Good answer, thank you! You're right, I chose a simple example mostly for the sake of clarity. I'm curious to try a `defmacro` or `define-inline` solution, so I'll probably take a stab at them. It would be nice to have `eval-when-compile` baked into the resulting expression.